# How do I configure IIS 7 to not look for generated cms pages?

Tags: iis-7, content-management-system, configure

I am using IIS7 and ASP.NET 4.0

I have a site that is using a CMS system (specifically AdxStudio).  Certain pages on the site are entirely generated using the CMS.  Currently, I must place a dummy file of the same name in the respective directory matching the url.  So, somesite.com/about/pressroom must have a file called '/about/pressroom/default.aspx', even though that file(page) is never served, but rather the one from the CMS is served.  However, if the dummy file is not there, the IIS gives a 404 error.

So, how do I configure IIS 7 so that the dummy 'default.aspx' file is not needed.  I am aware of URL Rewrite, but I am unsure if that will do what is needed or if there is some other configuration option that will suffice.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine AdxStudio has configuration recommendations for you to follow. This is absolutely a URL rewrite requirement and the details of that will vary with every application. We use it for parts catalogs, using part of the URL to identify a vendor. With several thousand vendors, it would be impossible for us to do what you've had to do.

So I suggest you get some help with AdxSudio specifically.

Edit: I also found this: [link](http://community.adxstudio.com/Default.aspx?DN=d9adbbe3-7ba9-433d-add9-f71b5e663bff#Add-the-Website-to-IIS-7) but i'm not sure how helpful it is to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this adx discussion that might help.

http://community.adxstudio.com/forums/adxstudio-cms/a66a74ec-f67d-4f72-a6d0-8ba7e84ab266

I hope this helps.